# select to recursive list

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, recursive-query

I have a data table that includes information about the directory tree -folders and documents
The table includes a column ID and column parentId

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
| id | parent | is_folder | details |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |        | TRUE      | …       |
|  2 |      1 | TRUE      | …       |
|  3 |      1 | TRUE      | …       |
|  4 |      1 | FALSE     | …       |
|  5 |      2 | TRUE      | …       |
|  6 |      5 | FALSE     | …       |
|  7 |      5 | TRUE      | …       |
|  8 |      7 | FALSE     | …       |
|  9 |      3 | FALSE     | …       |
| 10 |      3 | FALSE     | …       |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to make this list will be built as recursive directory tree

its return `IEnumerable<item>`

```
      public class item
    {
        public bool isFolder { get; set; } 
        public int id { get; set; }    
        public int parentId { get; set; }   //should???
        public string  details { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<item>  children { get; set; }  
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Create one item for each row, as you would do normally. Then, do something like this to create the childrens:

```
foreach(var item in items)
    item.children = items.Where(x => x.parentId == item.id);
```